# Canonical Live Patch Service : Response from server not easy

Tags: kernel, canonical, canonical-livepatch

I install last year "Canonical Live Patch Service", seem to work perfectly...

Today I just go to check if all is good and I have this answer :

---

root@vps187984494:~# canonical-livepatch status client-version: 9.4.4
 architecture: x86_64 cpu-model: Intel Core Processor (Haswell, no TSX)
 last-check: 2018-08-16T14:31:13+02:00 boot-time:
 2018-08-14T12:28:06+02:00 uptime: 10281h28m59s status:
 - kernel: 4.4.0-130.156-generic   running: true   livepatch:
     checkState: check-failed
     checkInfo: 'cannot send status to server: bad server status 403 (URL:
 https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine/1a86ee7503f042d0b5fa9c15f93f2f3c
 ):
       {"error": "Not checking for new patches based on reported livepatch state. State:
       kernel-upgrade-required"}'
     patchState: kernel-upgrade-required
     version: "42.1"
     fixes: |-
       * CVE-2017-17862
       * CVE-2018-1000004
       * CVE-2018-10323
       * CVE-2018-10840
       * CVE-2018-10877
       * CVE-2018-10881
       * CVE-2018-1092
       * CVE-2018-1093
       * CVE-2018-1094
       * CVE-2018-11412
       * CVE-2018-11506
       * CVE-2018-12233
       * CVE-2018-13094
       * CVE-2018-13405
       * CVE-2018-13406
       * CVE-2018-3665
       * CVE-2018-5390
       * CVE-2018-5391
       * CVE-2018-7755
       * CVE-2018-8087

### root@vps187984494:~#

I have difficulty to understand this response...
Some traduction needed ;-)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This may mean a CVE vulnerability occurred that cannot be live patched. It may require an upgrade via

```
# apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and rebooting with upgraded kernel.

"403" is a transient HTTPS error ("Forbidden"). You should retry the action at a later time.

Hope this helps.